# jQuery: How to find current object in Post callback data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I have an ajax post function:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
     var postData = ..some data..
     var targetDiv = $(this).closest(".someDiv");

     $.post(doucemnt.location, postData, function(data) {

         content = ... How to find targetDiv inside data here? ..

         targetDiv.html(content);
     });
});
```

The data returned from post will be the whole webpage, and I need to filter it and only get the div I want to refresh. I do not want to use any selectors by ID or class, because there are many copies of the "someDiv" and "button" inside each div, so I want to just get the div object of currently clicked button and search for it in callback data.

is that possible?

Comment: The scope of targetDiv allows you to use it inside the callback

Comment: what happens when you use your code? it looks ok to me

Comment: What do you mean, the element you get from the DOM and the element that exists in the string returned to the ajax function is not the same element ?

Comment: The porbolem is I can't get "content", is there a way find the object inside the "data" without using id or class, maybe by some reference or handler to the object itself?

Comment: Ah, so it looks like you have one page and are trying to load another page that has the same plaecholder code as this one does, but you want to replace this page's html with the one that you load it from.  You can't use Ids because you must spam out of list of those divs and buttons over and over or something...  Right?

Comment: @Daniel no it is same page, but the post response will return the whole page and I will need to filter the returned data and get only the div needed to be refreshed. And yes I want to avoid spamming IDs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question, so forgive me if I'm way off.
I think (if nothing else) this might help give you some ideas. I will parse through the response data looking for a specific 'hook'. Then return just that chunk of data...

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.button').click(function (event) {

// This would be your (real) ajax call.
doAjaxPost('www.location.com', postData, function (response) {
    var $refresh = $($.parseHTML(response)).filter('#refresh');
        $('#content').html($refresh);
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/damonjentree/Wds34/1/)